Teams webhook url access issue i/o error from java spring boot application
I have created a workflow in Teams and got the url using which I am able to send a postman request successfully. However when I am using that webhook url in java code I am getting the below error :
ResourceAccessException occurred: I/O error on POST request for "http://prod-33.westus.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/7162rryfrhf5757d0353274571e/triggers/manual/paths/invoke": Connection timed out: connect 
Here is the java code that I am using :
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    
    String webhookUrl = "my_url";
    
    
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    Map<String, Object> requestBody = new HashMap<>();
    requestBody.put("@type", "MessageCard");
    requestBody.put("@context", "http://schema.org/extensions");
    requestBody.put("@themeColor", "0076D7");
    requestBody.put("summary", "Hello-Java");

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity<Map<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, headers);

    try {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(webhookUrl, requestEntity, String.class);

        if (response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
            System.out.println("Message sent successfully!");
        } else {
            System.err.println("Error sending message: " + response.getStatusCode());
        }
    } catch (ResourceAccessException e) {
        System.err.println("ResourceAccessException occurred: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}

With Postman same url I am able to post messages in the teams group or channel. Not with Java . Can someone help.
UPDATE
Able to resolve the issue by removing the unwanted character like %2F but the webhook url is only working after I deploy in server. However from local env the issue is still there. I am still getting the same error.

"Connection timed out: connect" means you didn't get the response from the server within the default timeframe. If Postman is working and your Java app is not working, check if you have any HTTP proxy configured in Postman and do the same in your Java application. Most corporate networks have proxy.

@seenukarthi : no proxy configured in postman. its a simple post call.

As @seenukarthi pointed out in a comment, it's more than likely your corporate proxy. I would download the root certificate from your browser and add it to your JDK's cacerts and see if that helps.
How to import a .cer certificate into a java keystore?
You can download the cert from your browser through the certificate submenu.
Submenu Part 1
Submenu Part 2
